# Linked file always listed as dirty

Tags: git, eclipse-plugin, egit

I have a linked assembly file in an eclipse project (Code composer studio v5.3). The file has only been edited once since it was added to the project months ago, yet the file is constantly marked as dirty and shown in the unstaged changes pane of the Git Repository perspective.

If I try a commit of just this file I get an error that there are no changes.

If it gets listed as part of a commit with other files then the commit runs OK, but the asm file is not actually committed.

I have tried `git status` from git bash on the project and it does not list the asm file

I have tried setting it to `assume unchanged` but nothing happens...

I have other linked files of various types (.asm, .c, .cmd, etc) in the project that do not suffer the same problem...

How can I find out what is causing this and solve it?

PS: Bear in mind I'm a total n00b at git, am only able to use it thus far as EGit removes the need for me to learn and recall all the ins & outs of CLI commands etc!

Comment: What version of EGit are you using?

Comment: @robinst, just thought to check that, I am using 2.1, tried updating to 2.3 (latest CCCS eclipse base version supports) but it gave an error that there is a conflicting dependency... How can I find out what the conflicting dependency is?

Comment: OK, updated to 2.3 but this has not helped. Though the unstaged change for the linked file now shows as as a removal of the same file (has little grey x icon decoration in staging pane)....

Comment: Are we talking about linked resources in the Eclipse sense or a symbolic in the file system sense?

Comment: Um..Linked in Eclipse sense. That is if I check the file properties > resource > type it is `Linked` and the location is marked as the correct one (using a path variable) and it is also shown, similarly to other linked files in the linked resources pane.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The update to EGit v2.3 did solve some other annoyances I had been seeing. But looking at the repo using Git Extensions I realised I had a copy of the linked file sitting in the repo directory - essentially duplicating the file in the project (i.e. there was a copy of the asm file in the project dir BUT the project settings was telling the project to also go link to the same asm file at another location).

I figured this might be snarling up the .project file somehow so I removed the link from the project, rebuilt and sure enough the file from the project dir was added to the project. The subsequent commit and push ran OK!

Comment: FYI, in EGit 2.3 we fixed some problems with linked resources (they were not really working before), so that explains it. See the [new and noteworthy page for 2.3](https://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/New_and_Noteworthy/2.3).